# Input JS binding functions not running after re-write

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently trying to bind all functions of my input to the document because I'm reloading the input with AJAX. I've tried this but it is strange because it's not working anymore:

```
let val = jQuery("input#val");
jQuery(document).on('keypress', val, function (e) {
    if (8 !== e.which && 0 !== e.which && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) return !1
});
jQuery(document).on('keyup', val, function () {
    jQuery(this).val(function (e, t) {
        return t.replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".")
    })
});
jQuery(document).on('bind', val, function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
});
jQuery(document).on('focus', val, function () {
    jQuery(this).parent().addClass("has-focus");
}).blur(function () {
    jQuery(this).parent().removeClass("has-focus");
});
```

What did I wrong?

Comment: all of above code is inside `$(document).ready()` ?

Comment: Yes sir. It is inside. I've just changed it from val.keypress(function ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using a delegated event handler the selector argument needs to be a string, not a jQuery object as you're currently using.

Note in the example below the use of the `$` alias in the document.ready event handler which allows you to retain a reference to `jQuery` through the more succinct `$` variable.

Finally, check the `blur` event is working as you expect as you're attaching it to the `document`, not the `input`. I've updated the answer to delegate the event too. Try this:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  let val = 'input#val'; // this needs to be a string

  $(document).on('keypress', val, function(e) {
    if (8 !== e.which && 0 !== e.which && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) return !1
  });

  $(document).on('keyup', val, function() {
    $(this).val(function(e, t) {
      return t.replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".")
    })
  });

  $(document).on('bind', val, function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
  });

  $(document).on('focus', val, function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass("has-focus");
  });

  $(document).on('blur', val, function() {
    $(this).parent().removeClass("has-focus");
  });
});
```

Comment: Everything works with the string  instead of the blur event as you already told. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: You just need to use `$(document).on('blur', val, function() {...` as you do everywhere else.

Comment: So you mean split it into 2 functions instead of one?

Comment: Yes. I updated the answer to show you exactly how to do it.

Comment: Already did it and it's working. Thanks for your fast answer. I'm using .on not that much so I was confused. Thanks for your help. Checking you answer when I'm allowed to.